# How can I pass in the specified disk to a macro on the FilesystemAdapter in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a Macro that returns the CDN url for a given Storage::disk in Laravel. In the macro, I want to access the specified disk and return the CDN url for that given disk.
Here is the code for the macro:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class StorageMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if (!function_exists('cdnUrl'))
        {
            FilesystemAdapter::macro('cdnUrl', function ($filename) {
                $diskName = $this->getDriver();
                dd($diskName);
                return Storage::disk($diskName)->url($filename);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And this is the way I'm calling the macro:

```
Storage::disk('local')->cdnUrl('test');
```

When I change the `Storage::disk('local')` to `Storage::disk('public')` the `$diskName` changes accordingly. However, I am unable to access the disk name for the given driver.

I am aware that the $diskName is a `League\Flysystem\Filesystem` object, but I would like to be able to access the name as specified in the `Storage::disk('local')->cdnUrl('test')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of **Storage::disk()** is to help to determine what kind of adapter instance will be returned.

By default, the driver of local disk is **local**:

```
 'local' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root' => storage_path('app'),
     'throw' => false,
 ],
```

For local driver, **Storage::disk('local')** will return an instance of **FilesystemAdapter**. So it's not necessary to know disk name in FilesystemAdapter::macro. You just need to do:

```
FilesystemAdapter::macro('cdnUrl', function ($filename) {   
     return $this->url($filename);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works. I have marked your answer as accepted.